# How to limit the amount of checked boxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating a script to limit the amount of checkboxes that are checked but my script is disabling all checkboxes on the page.

How can I disable only one checkbox inside the div, in the example I did this is disabling all the checkboxes where I want to disable only the checkbox of the first div.

I want the script to run only for the first div

Here's an example of the code:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var marcados = 0; //cheked
  var limitChoices = 2; // limit
  var verifyCheckeds = function($checks) {
    if (marcados >= limitChoices && limitChoices != 0) {
      loop($checks, function($element) {
        $element.disabled = $element.checked ? '' : 'disabled';
      });
    } else {
      loop($checks, function($element) {
        $element.disabled = '';
      });
    }
  };
  var loop = function($elements, cb) {
    var max = $elements.length;
    while (max--) {
      cb($elements[max]);
    }
  }
  var count = function($element) {
    return $element.checked ? marcados + 1 : marcados - 1;
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    const elementodiv = document.getElementById("1question-80-1");
    var $checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    loop($checks, function($element) {
      $element.onclick = function() {
        marcados = count(this);
        verifyCheckeds($checks);
      }
      if ($element.checked) marcados = marcados + 1;
    });
    verifyCheckeds($checks);
  }
}());
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span>Div 1</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="div2">
  <span>Div 2</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="div3">
  <span>Div 3</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: @j08691 I agree. I removed the tag.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What exactly is not working currently?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Limit cheked checkbox</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div">
      <span>Div 1</span>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <span>Div 2</span>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="div">
  <span>Div 3</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><span>Test</span>
  </div>

</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      "use strict";

      
      window.onload = function () {
        const elementodiv = document.getElementById("1question-80-1");
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
        Array.from(divs).forEach(x => {
            var marcados = 0; //cheked
      var limitChoices = 2; // limit
      var verifyCheckeds = function ($checks) {
        if (marcados >= limitChoices && limitChoices != 0) {
          loop($checks, function ($element) {
            $element.disabled = $element.checked ? '' : 'disabled';
          });
        } else {
          loop($checks, function ($element) {
            $element.disabled = '';
          });
        }
      };
      var loop = function ($elements, cb) {
        var max = $elements.length;
        while (max--) {
          cb($elements[max]);
        }
      }
      var count = function ($element) {
        return $element.checked ? marcados + 1 : marcados - 1;
      }
   
            var $checks = x.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        loop($checks, function ($element) {
          $element.onclick = function () {
            marcados = count(this);
            verifyCheckeds($checks);
          }
          if ($element.checked) marcados = marcados + 1;
        });
        verifyCheckeds($checks);
        });
        }
     
    }());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well you did it almost perfect. Just need some tweaks.

First, I reassigned the class names `div1`, `div2`, and `div3` to just `div`. As I wanted my JS to be applied to all of them similarly.

Next, I've put all the global functions inside the `forEach` iterator function.
I tried it and it got the job done.

Comment: Please take the time to explain your code, how/why it works, what it's doing; that way OP - and future visitors - can learn from you, and this answer. I'd also argue that a class-name of `"div"` is a little meaningless, I understand *why* you did it, but I'd personally have chosen something like `"checkbox-wrapper"`, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

onclick will accept argument so you could access event.target and there you can dig trough parent nodes to limit elements that you manipulate. That put a lot of pressure on maintaining that html structure but should scale to any amount of containers and elements inside

```
   $element.onclick = function (event) {
            marcados = count(this);
            verifyCheckeds(
            $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).find('input')
```

);
}